# Magento: moving related products to associated products

Tags: sql, magento, entity-attribute-value, product, magmi

With my infinite wisdom of Magento (which was practically non-existent 3 months ago), I decided to tell my wife, aunt, sister-in-law and other housewives of our family to help and help us fill our webshop with grouped products and have them add the products that should be associated with that grouped product to the 'related products'-list. (aargh!)

Now, near the end of filling the 9000+ products we have in the webshop, I discovered that it is absolutely required to have them all in the "associated products"-list instead of the "related products"-list. **Is there a way to edit all grouped products in such a way where I can convert the entire collection of "related products" to "associated products"?**

*Things I've tried myself:*

- I've tried exporting and importing with MagMI, but I couldn't figure out how to do it correctly.. importing prices, categories, stock (qty), setting other attributes.. everything works, except this.
- I've tried diving in to the complex eav-model of Magento's database to see if I could just change an ID somewhere in the hope that THAT would solve it, but I kinda lost my way in the forrest of Magento's tables. (thank goodness for database backups)

Can anyone tell me how to move these "related products" to the "associated products" list?

Answer (score 0):

associated products requires a "configurable" or a "grouped" product type that will have then "simple" products associated to it.

If your products are already compatible with this, then magmi configurable plugin (in case of configurable) or magmi grouped plugin (in case of grouped) could do the thing easily at import.

- Fill `simples_skus` column with the skus to "associate" with your master product in case of configurable product. Forc configurable products, you'll also need "pivot" attributes that will constitute the "variations" you want to express on your master product and that will be implemented by each of your simple products.
- Fill `grouped_skus` columns with the skus to "associate" with your master product in case of grouped product.No need for pivot attributes since a grouped product is a "bag of product"

Then for removing related products, use the `re_skus` column , and fill it with `-re::.*` , which mean remove all related skus matching regexp: `.*` , => "everything"

Comment: It's only for the 'grouped products' items; We stayed clear from adding related products to 'simple products'.. I'll have a look at your comment and see if it works.